# Changing Marketo sandbox to integrate with MS CRM from Salesforce

Tags: dynamics-crm, marketo

I currently have a Marketo Sandbox that is configured to integrate with Salesforce.com.

I need to change this to a MS Dynamics CRM instance, but can't see how to do this.

I don't need to retain the existing Salesforce configuration at all.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you configure a Marketo sandbox to sync with a CRM organization (SFDC or MSCRM) you can't change that configuration, they are basically paired for life.

Per the [Marketo Documentation](http://docs.marketo.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=3571830) Enable Sync-> Step 2.

> Warning: Once Marketo and CRM are synced, there is no switching allowed to any another[sic] CRM subscription

If you open a support ticket Marketo will be able to "reset" the org so that you can connect the new Marketo sandbox to MSCRM instead.

**Note** that you'll run into the same issue if you end up wanting to point to another MSCRM org, or even if you are using MSCRM sandboxes and reset your MSCRM sandbox.